# No carga imagen en HTML. Django

Tags: python, django

No comprendo por que la imagen no me carga. La ruta esta bien especificada. He probado de varias formas, pero nada.

**HTML**

```
{% load static i18n %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>

<title> prueba </title>

</head>

<body>

    <h2> Imagen </h2>

    <p>
    <img src="{% static 'images/logo2.png' %}" alt="Foto" />
    </p>

</body>

</html>
```

**Imágenes para comprobar la ubicación**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**SETTINGS**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**PAGINA**

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][4]][4]

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][4]][4]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Agregaste la configuración de la ruta en el settings?

Comment: Actualice la consulta para que se vea como lo tengo en el setting

Comment: Inténtalo con la etiqueta ```{% static "images/logo2.png" %}```

Comment: Eso va dentro de una etiqueta?

Comment: Así: ```<img src="{% static 'images/logo2.png' %}" alt="Foto" />``` También intenta sin ```i18n``` en ```{% load static %}``` solo para probarlo.

Comment: Lo probé de ambas formas, pero todo sigue igual...

Comment: Tenes algun complemento o extension instalado no? Claramente dice que te lo bloquea DevTools, de alguna manera bastante extraña te divide la imagen en 2 request. Proba desactivando dicho complemento o herramienta a ver que pasa.

Comment: No comprendo como, pero lo solucione. Lo único que hice fue poner "DEBUG = False" en el Settings, y luego lo volvi a poner en TRUE. Al hacer esto se arreglo el problema. Gracias a todos...